# ubuntu machine loses internet access after creating bridge

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, bridge, linux-kvm

I make a bridge to connect my VMs to which are hosted in an Ubuntu 16.04. Through the VMs I can ping google and access internet. But my host loses internet access. I know its local Ip and I can ping it from other devices in the network but It can's access internet.

I have also a wireless connection whether connected or disconnected the problem remains.

Comment: Have you checked your network configuration on the host. If you can ping but can't connect to a website it sounds like you don't have a DNS server configured in your settings

Comment: I have set the line 
"dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8" 
in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Have you tried pinging to a website (not an ip address)? e.g. ping google.com

Comment: yes, non of them works.

Comment: that means there is a problem with DNS. Do you have a dynamic or static Ip address, and if dynamic, where is your DHCP server located?

Comment: I have a router connected to my laptop. I dont have an ethernet port and I use a Ethernet to USB module. If config shows no IP is assigned to it. But when I ping to an unreachable destination, it says my IP is 192.168.0.132

Comment: Can you add the results from ifconfig to your question please